# Magento Error on Product Pages Invalid attribute name: custom_use_parent_settings

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I updated mageto 1.4 to 1.5 all things fine, 
but the product page returns follow error. also i can't index

Indexed category/products association  and Index product prices  the label showing processing 
when i click on reindex it appears **There was a problem with reindexing process**.

i tried deleting loc files and cache and some operations on db but no luck
 can any one help me for this pls
thank you

http://hellteam.bizarsoftware.com.au/technical-downloads/general-tech-essays-misc.html

```
Invalid attribute name: custom_use_parent_settings.

    Trace:
    #0 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1166): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid attribu...')
    #1 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1255): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_addAttributeJoin('custom_use_pare...', 'inner')
    #2 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(292): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_getAttributeConditionSql('custom_use_pare...', 0, 'inner')
    #3 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(312): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter('custom_use_pare...', 0)
    #4 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category.php(589): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addFieldToFilter('custom_use_pare...', 0)
    #5 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php(841): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category->getParentDesignCategory(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
    #6 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Design.php(348): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category->getParentDesignCategory(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
    #7 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/local/FastDivision/Comet/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(38): Mage_Catalog_Model_Design->getDesignSettings(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
    #8 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): FastDivision_Comet_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
    #9 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
    #10 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #11 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #12 /home/hellteam/public_html/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #13 /home/hellteam/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #14 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a magento database upgrade I had a similar problem when visting a product listing page. The error that was logged under var/report/ was:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'custom_use_parent_settings' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table` WHERE (entity_id IN ('105', '9', '5', '1')) AND (custom_use_parent_settings = 0) AND (`level` != 0) ORDER BY `level` DESC

What I did to fix was:

1. Flush Magento cache in System -> Cache Management
2. Rebuild all indexes in System > Index Management